# How to use SimpleBlobDetector in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection

What does [`SimpleBlobDetector`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html?highlight=simpleblobdetector#SimpleBlobDetector%20:%20public%20FeatureDetector) actually do?

It returns some points to me, but what are these points?

Does the blob detector find image regions of similar properties, including colors?

Can I retrieve the contour of the found blobs? I saw `detectEx` function calls in some examples on the web, but see no such function in OpenCV 2.4.5. What is used instead of this function now?

**UPDATE**

Here is how the blob detecting algorithm is described in the docs:

1. Convert the source image to binary image by applying thresholding
   with several thresholds from minThreshold (inclusive) to
   maxThreshold (exclusive) with distance thresholdStep between
   neighboring thresholds.
2. Extract connected components from every
   binary image by findContours() and calculate their centers.
3. Group centers from several binary images by their coordinates. Close
   centers form one group that corresponds to one blob, which is
   controlled by the minDistBetweenBlobs parameter.
4. From the groups, estimate final centers of blobs and their radiuses and return as
   locations and sizes of keypoints.

It is not clear that blobs should be circular!

Answer (score 4):

The points it returns are the centres of the blobs in the image. The blobs are assumed to be circular, and the size stored as the size of the keypoints in the output vector that is obtained with the `detect()` function. You can specify the colour of the blobs you are looking for by using filtering based on colour, as specified in your link. Set `filterByColor = true` and specify the colour you are looking for in `blobColor`.

If you're looking for contours, you will need to break the process down into finer steps. First threshold to obtain a binary image. Then use the `findContours` function in OpenCV.

Comment: How to merge contours, containing the similar color content?

Comment: Do you mean to merge blobs or merge contours? I'm not clear on how you would merge contours..?

Comment: I can just put them in single bag. Later I can calculate joined area or make a hull.

Comment: P.S. if blobs are circles, then what does convexity limit means?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I would merge in a brute force manner, by checking the proximity of the ends of all contours, and by comparing their pixel colours. Any contours whose ends almost touch, and whose ends are of similar colours may be merged.

Comment: I don't think it does actually. Another way you can ensure that the contours don't get split up is by doing a morphological "close" operation i.e. a dilation followed by an erosion, on the binary image before finding contours. I'm afraid I don't understand what convexity limit is.

Comment: Re your update.. The function doesn't say that the blobs _should_ be circular. It simply estimates the best fit circle for each blob and stores the centre and radius of the circle as the centre and size of the returned keypoint.